# Cannot call Selenium 2 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver" from C#

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

When trying to call System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver" from C#, LinqPad says setProperty cannot be found in System.

Actually System doesn't exist in any Selenium dll for c# so is it possible or did I miss something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `System.setProperty()` is Java, see [doc here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

What are you trying to do?

If you just want to set the path to ie driver, here is how to do it in C# ([doc here](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/dotnet/index.html)):

```c#
// for other overloads, check the doc please
IWebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\PathTo\IEDriverServer");
```